# Unable to access Arduino Yun board using arduino.local

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

Windows machine: After configuring on-board WiFi, I cannot access Arduino Yun board using `arduino.local`. However while configuring, I gave name of the board exactly `arduino`.

Linux (Ubuntu): However if I repeat same steps configuring WiFi in Ubuntu, I can access its webpanel using `arduino.local` in browser.

Any solution how can I access from a `Windows` machine. Or how to figure out IP address of the board to access its webpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions on their [site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun) very carefully.

Specifically:

> NB: The Yún uses Bonjour services for auto-discovery on a wireless network. This service is not included with Windows by default. If you do not have Bonjour already installed, you can download the service from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). Additionally, you should make sure any anti-virus software is not blocking communication on port 5353.